# How to read file from GCP bucket?

Tags: java, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

below code i'm using to read file

```
 Map<String, InputStream> allFiles = this.storageService.getObjectsInDirectory(path, bucket);
```

it is reading file from all **directories** and its **sub directories**  just want to read files from **directory** only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As explained in [this document](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/folders#overview)-

> Cloud Storage operates with a flat namespace, which means that folders don't actually exist within Cloud Storage. If you create an object named folder1/file.txt in the bucket your-bucket, the path to the object is your-bucket/folder1/file.txt, but there is no folder named folder1; instead, the string folder1 is part of the object's name.

Hence, they are emulated using the `prefix` and `delimiter` parameters to the [List Objects](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/list) method.

For example, if you have `folder1` with `img1` and `sub-folder1`. If `delimiter` is set to "/" and prefix is not set, then it will return only `img1` and `sub-folder1`. And  If `delimiter` is set to "/" and prefix is set to "sub-folder1/", it will list objects from the subfolder also.

You can also check this [code sample](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/listing-objects#list-objects) for listing objects